# Recognize wide Unicode point on Windows narrow Python build

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I have a narrow Python 2.7.6 build on Windows. I also have a string containing both "narrow" (< 0x10000) and "wide" (> 0xFFFF) Unicode code points.

```
>>> wide1 = u'\U0002b740'
>>> wide2 = u'\ud86d\udf40'
>>> wide1 == wide2
True
>>> narrow = u'\ud86d'
>>> s = wide1 + narrow
```

But when I iterate over the string, it doesn't recognize wide code points:

```
>>> for c in s:
>>>   c
u'\ud86d'
u'\udf40'
u'\ud86d'
```

And it becomes impossible to find out whether a char was a narrow code point or it was a part of a wide code point.

Comment: Please be aware that `narrow` strings / text / characters and so forth normally denotes a byte-based encoding, like ASCII / UTF-8 / Latin-1, not UTF-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. High Unicode codepoints are internally represented as UTF-16 surrogates.

The U+D86D and U+DF40 codepoints are such surrogates, you should never see this in normal Unicode text usage anyway. Quoting from the [Wikipedia article on UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF):

> The Unicode standard permanently reserves these code point values for UTF-16 encoding of the lead and trail surrogates, and they will never be assigned a character, so there should be no reason to encode them. The official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points.

As such the U+D800 to U+DFFF codepoints should not be treated as narrow points; they are one half of a wide codepoint, that is their purpose.